# Relating Consule and HAProxy

Tags: java, deployment, load-balancing, haproxy, consul

How does HAProxy and Consule relate each other?

The vendor sites mentioned Consule is use for service discover and configuration while HAProxy use to load balance.

So is it like first we have to make our service discoverable using Consule and then use HAProxy for load balance? Cant we do load balance only with Consule?

Comment: Consul? See: https://hashicorp.com/blog/haproxy-with-consul.html

Comment: consul-haproxy is deprecated. It recommend to use consul-template. Do you have any idea how to do load balancing using consul-template?

Comment: There is a haproxy example on the consul-template webpage, see: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template